# how to make compiz wobbly effect ignore a single window?

Tags: compiz, effects, lightning

I have the reminders/alerts popup window with Thunderbird/lightning calendar, that I need to avoid it being managed by wobbly compiz effect, because I already set another rule to make it have minimal size (25x70) when not maximized, and it seems to conflict with wobbly; so it just wobbly every time I click and that is annoying...

But I can find no way to exclude that window from wobbly... there is no option, and nobody in the whole internet seems to have asked that before :)

any tips?

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to give you all of the relevant information w/o screen shots since I use A.D.D helper, as my screen shots will be darkened. Go to your Wobbly windows plug-in in CCSM, and remove the `unknown` tag, then click the `+` button. A window will appear, allowing you to add to the window list. With the window you want to skip open click the `Grab` button then click on the window. Then click the `invert` tick box, then `OK`. Voilà your done, however note that AFAIK this cannot select a single window from a single program, only selected types, so all windows of this type will be skipped. Don't fret however there may be a solution for you, the first drop-down box contains a list of `Types`.

`Window class` will be very broad: normal, dialog, modaldialog etc.

`Window Title` is, you guessed it by title (probably where I would start if I were the op).

`Window Name` is likely a hex name or a name given to the window by the WM, and might work, as it might not be unique to one and only one window.

`Window ID` will be unique, but might change per session, I'm not to certain I would try it.

`Window Role` is another generic label: notification, panel, toolbox, etc.

`Window Type` is likely to be another generic name convention, and it's not likely to work for you.

Note: I could be wrong about the types, but I would try `xprop` on the window to get all relevant information on it first, before making any changes, just to be certain that you select the right type.

`xprop` spews more info than you will need, look for these:

`WM_NAME(STRING) = "Window Name"`

`WM_CLASS(STRING) = "windowclass", "Windowclass"`

`WM_TRANSIENT_FOR(WINDOW): window id # 0xc00003`

`WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0xc00001`

Beware: some windows (most i think) will give output like this:

`_NET_WM_...`

I'm fairly certain that what is in these field isn't what your looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh, the **invert** option did the trick thx!! btw I think an "almost single window" can be filtered like in: `(Toolbar | Menu | Utility | Dialog | Normal | Unknown ) & !(class=Thunderbird & name=Calendar & role=AlarmWindow & type=Dialog)`